# Does 前の方 have the same nuance of 前方

Tags: translation, words, sentence

すごい行列だ
でも、運良く前の方に並べたし

"What a big line. But luckily, I was standing..."

Does it mean the front part? Or does it mean he was standing there fro before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前の方 refers to the front part of the queue.

[image]

前の方 and 前方【ぜんぽう】 are roughly the same, but people seldom say 運良く前方に並べた in practice because 前方 sounds stiffer. When reserving a bus seat in polite Japanese, 前の方の座席をお願いします and 前方の座席をお願いします are exactly the same.